# Can't access a folder on a subdomain on bluehost

Tags: server, bluehost

I've tried my best but can't seem to find anyone with the same issue I have, specifically with bluehost.

I have a main domain with bluehost and hosting.  Just as an example, let's call it helloworld.com.

I then purchased another domain goodbyeworld.com with bluehost.  Then I created a subdomain hello.goodbyeworld.com which pointed to a specific folder named goodbyeworld on my main hosting account.

As a result, both helloworld.com/goodbyeworld and hello.goodbyeworld.com should show point to the same directory.

The issue I'm having is, I have a folder named 'icons' in the goodbyeworld folder that has a single file named icon.png.

I can't seem to figure out why helloworld.com/goodbyeworld/icons/icon.png works, but hello.goodbyeworld.com/icons/icon.png doesn't work even though they both technically point to the same location.  However, everything else works.  For example, I have a folder named 'images' and i can access everything in that folder fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm perplexed.

Comment: Is that shared server or dedicated ?

Comment: dedicated, I believe.  I have the business pro hosting.
For now, I renamed the folder to icon_images and it works fine.  I guess it's specific to 'icons'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what Bluehost support told me: "The issue is that by default, directories named "icons" link to the Apache OS's icons directory.  Renaming that "icons" to "icon" should fix it."